# How do i make a serializer field show only to the logged in user in django rest framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

Hi how are you? I am making an e-commerce API and the issue I am facing is that when a user signs up it shows the user who signed up and the data along with it. How do I just make that data available to a user in json if he is logged into his or her account?

when you sign up in the /sign-up endpoint it shows all the data a user just entered!
how do I restrict that data to be viewed only by the authenticated owner of his or her account?

The field is write_only, I want to extract the data in dict format like I would do with a read_only field.

thanks!

Comment: or could someone tell me how to extract a write_only serializer field's data of a user?

Comment: Showing the code you already have will make it easier to answer as the person who answers will not have to think up the code but modify what you have

Comment: i figured it out :) thanks bro